# Server Error in Application when hosting Web Service on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, hosting, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to host my web service that is done in ASP.NET on Azure. I managed to get the front page to be displayed correctly, however, when I click on a button to direct to another page, it gives me the following error:

[image]

I have tried adding the following code in my web.config, web.debug.config and web.release.config:

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

I have also tried uncommenting the following in my web.debug.config and web.release.config, but it did not work:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
        mode="On" xdt:Transform="Replace">
        <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
      </customErrors>
```

However, I do not encounter errors when I run it on localhost.

Can anyone help with this? Been trying to debug it for quite a while and I have tried following online sources but have still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your mentioned screenshot, it just the common information. You could follow  [Troubleshoot a web app in Azure App Service using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug) document to troubleshoot. Such as add custom error off in the Web.config file or [remoting debug webApps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug), etc.

[image]

[image]

[image]